# Array returning undefined at higher granularity

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, csv, object

I am using AJAX to read a CSV file in to an Object of Arrays. The problem I'm having is that the data is being read correctly and appears to be in the Object but if I move down the layers I get undefined messages. Even though in the top view of the object everything is there. I think it might have something to do with timing as I am working with large amounts of data.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = readCSV();
    populateTable(data);
});

function readCSV() {
    var data = {"columns":[], "rows":[]};

    $.ajax({
        url : 'assets/php/readCSV.php',
        type : 'POST',
        success : function (csv) {
            var colCount = csv[0].length,
                rowCount = csv.length;

            for (var c = 0; c < colCount; c++) {
                data['columns'][c] = csv[0][c];
            }

            csv.splice(0,1);

            for (var r = 0; r < rowCount; r++) {
                data['rows'][r] = csv[r];
            }
        },
        error : function () {
            alert("Error: Unable to read the CSV file. Please try again.");
        }
    });

    return data;
}

function populateTable(data) {
    console.log(data); // Outputs all the data as expected.
    console.log(data['columns']); // Shows the columns data as expected
    console.log(data['columns'][0]); // Returns undefined
}
```

**Snip-it of first console log**

```
Object { columns=[0],  rows=[0]}
columns     ["EXPERIMNT CODE", "EXPERIMNT_NAME", "VarCode", 12 more...]
rows    [["H1225", "COP - Show star rating a...ting in the price panel", "H1225:001.000", 12 more...], ["H1225", "COP - Show star rating a...ting in the price panel", "H1225:001.001", 12 more...], ["H1225", "COP - Show star rating a...ting in the price panel", "H1225:001.002", 12 more...], 4873 more...]
```

**snip-it of second console log**

```
[]          
0   "EXPERIMNT CODE"
1   "EXPERIMNT_NAME"
2   "VarCode"
3   "VarName"
4   "Version Number"
5   "Reporting Range Start Date"
6   "Reporting Range End Date"
7   "Status"
8   "Transaction Date"
9   "EXPERIMNT TEST ID"
10  "Test Manager"
11  "Product Manager"
12  "Pod"
13  "Record_Update_Datetm"
14  "Insert_datetm"
```

Third just returns undefined even though from the second snip-it you can see the data is there.

Whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "A" in "Ajax" stands for "asynchronous". This mean that when you make the ajax request execution continues immediately with the next line after `$.ajax()` in your `readCSV()` function without waiting for the response. So your `readCSV()` function returns before the response and thus should be returning `{"columns":[], "rows":[]}`. Later, when the response is received, your `success` callback will be executed, but by then your `populateTable()` function has already been invoked.

The only explanation I can think of for why the console logs are showing any of the returned data is that in some browsers the console will retain a live link to the logged object. So the console initially shows `Object { columns=[0],  rows=[0]}` because the arrays were empty at the time the `console.log(data)` ran (note the zeros), and `data['columns'][0]` was `undefined` at that moment. But then by the time you click on that object in the console to expand it and see the contents of the arrays the ajax response will have been received and the arrays have been populated.

The fix for all this is simply to call `populateTable()` from within your `success` handler, because at that point the data will definitely be available.